# Using CudnnLSTM gives this error: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' in kaggle kernel

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kaggle

I'm trying to run my code on kaggle kerne. This is my model in keras

```
inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
emb = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)
x2 = Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(64, return_sequences=True))(x1)
max_pl = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x2)
x = Dense(16, activation="relu")(max_pl)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
```

But because of CuDNNGRU I get:  No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'.
How should I fix this on kaggle kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I put together this quick example in Kaggle based on your structure.  Note how the CuDNNGRU is called.  I hope this helps.

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,))
emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(20, 4)(inp)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(64, return_sequences=True))(emb)
max_pl = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x2)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(max_pl)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```